# Constrain numeric value in JTextField to a specific range, with defaults

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, default-value

Not sure how to write this in JAVA...
I need to code that will insert a default value (say 50) if user keys in a value outside of a given range of 10-100 feet. I have it working for errors if blank or non integer is entered or value is outside the range but cannot figure out how to integrate a default. 
What I have that works is

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    poolLength = new JTextField(10);
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Enter the pool's length (ft):"));
    panel1.add(poolLength);
```

What I want to add is something like this

```
If poolLength <10 or >200 then poolLength = 100
        Else this.add(panel1);
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Yes, please add code showing your work so far.

Comment: The question depends on context, do  you want post validation or realtime validation

Comment: Use `JSpinner` instead of `JTextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to get the text during e.g. an `ActionEvent`, parse it and reset the text if it's outside the range.

```
jTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean isValid = true;

        try {
            int intVal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
            if (intVal < 10 || intVal > 200) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            // user entered something which is not an int
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (!isValid) {
            jTextField.setText("100");
        }
    }
});
```

Also see [*How to Use Text Fields*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

Another way would be to [use a spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) which does something like this by default.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: **I do not know Swing well**, actually, I dont remember much at all..

**Maybe** you simply need to attach a validator to your JTextField?

[Here you have an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749521/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield), however please notice that in that post they check for the length of the text, not the contents. But having the text, you can easily parse it as a number and check if it is greater/lower than the bounds.

As you see in that post, by returning true/false you will prevent the user from entering a wrong value - ie. too small. Now, when wrong value is detected, then, instead of returning 'false',  **maybe** it is possible to simply `myjtextfield.setText("50.0")` on that input? That may do exactly what you wanted.

really, be careful with those "maybe"s: I do not know Swing, but from general UI framework design, trying to "setText" may:

- throw an exception: many frameworks think it's quite evil to change the field's value during validation and defend themselves against it
- cause strange issues when editing: if that JTextEdit calls validation upon every single change of the text, you will notice odd things when trying to, i.e. select-all, delete, write 123. You'll end up with 50.0123 or 12350.0 as the JTextEdit **might** try to validate the intermediate empty text after deletion and coerce it to "50.0"..
- or, it may just work.

So, if your time is critical, just try it. Maybe I guessed well. But, if you have some time to spare, wait until someone checks that I didn't write any nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead.

[image]

It will not behave exactly as described, but provide a better user experience.  The user can adjust the value with the <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> buttons.  If they type a value outside the specified range, it will revert to the last valid value when the field loses focus.