# Force the user to add only Hebrew letters

Tags: java, if-statement, unicode, jtextfield, hebrew

How can I make a `JTextfield` accept only Hebrew letters with if statement?
I can do a long if statement with all the Hebrew letters but it will not look good.
I found out that the Unicode of Hebrew first letter is `\u05D0` and last one is `\u05EA`.
How can I say that if the gettext is in between these 2 letters so show (meaning to check if the text entered is only a Hebrew letter), the user will add only one letter in each textfield.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean `if (0x05D0 <= ch && ch <= 0x05EA)`  to check it is ok.

Comment: @PeterLawrey
Yes something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `JTextField` and this class inherits `getText()` method which returns a `String`. So, this is how I will probably do it.

```
String name = jTextField.getText();
char[] charArray = name.toCharArray();
for (char c : charArray) {
    if (!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0)) {
        break;
        //valid
    }
}
```

This can become more efficient, if you keep the counter of elements added/removed, you only will have to check the latest entered character (in case of removal you probably won't need that but that scenario will need more coding, so I hope you will figure that out once you solves this issue).

Update:

This is what I have tried:

```
        String name      = "אבגa";
        char[] charArray = name.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if (c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0) {
                System.out.println("Valid hebrew");
            }
        }
```

And this prints `Valid hebrew` three times.

Comment: Thank you really.
But some reasons it doesn't work for me !
Can we make the char String ?

Comment: I tried it but it seems the check is not done 
`    if (btn.getSelectedItem().equals("\u05E2\u05D1\u05E8")) {
     
     String first;
     Swing get = new Swing();
     first = get.getfl();
     char [] charArray = first.toCharArray();
     for(char c : charArray) {
      if (c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
      }
     }`

Comment: @AboelmagdSaad Can you tell me the input you have in your textfield?

Comment: sure, I tried with english letters like (a or b) and then went to the combobox and chose the first action I want , and no errors happened at all

Comment: @AboelmagdSaad Check the updated answer. Code is checking for valid herbrew characters. If these are valid, it will go inside the `if` otherwise, not.

Comment: I knew the error :D
I missed to add !=
if (!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0))
Now it works

Comment: done :)
Thank you so much
But can we run the check only one time, because for now, the error message appears twice for me and not only one time !

Comment: Updated the answer to validate once. @AboelmagdSaad

Answer (score 3):

Build an input validator with your validation logic, and attach it to your textField to verify input as you enter it. Steps: Combine the validation logic given by @peter-lawray with the mechanism of building an [input verifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749521/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield) and you're good to go.

Comment: @mohsenmadi
Thank you so much, but I feel this is a little more advanced for me

Comment: No problem :-). If I were you and you are new to all this, I would invest the time into learning JavaFX if you want to build desktop apps. JavaFX is the new GUI framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple one-liner using a Stream

`boolean valid = jTextField.getText().chars().allMatch(p -> p <= 0x05ea && p >= 0x05d0);`

Answer (score 1):

Putting the other answers together, this is an input validator you could use:

```
// adapted from mohsenmadi/Daniel Rikowski
public class HebrewVerifier extends InputVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
        // method suggested by Mad Matts
        return text.chars().allMatch(p -> p <= 0x05ea && p >= 0x05d0);
    }
}
```

And then you simply need to attach it to your `JTextField`:

```
myHebrewTextField.setInputVerifier(new HebrewVerifier());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
//...
 public static String readHebrewString()
    {
        String str="";
        System.out.println("הקלד שורה");      
        InputStreamReader in;
        try {
            char[]buffer=new char[1024];
            in = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "Windows-1255");
            in.read(buffer);
            int i=0;
            while((int)buffer[i]!=10)
                  str+=buffer[i++];
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Demo001.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Demo001.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Every time you use `+=` on `str`, a new `string` object is created. The memory consumption of your loop is the amount of characters squared and then divided by 2.