# How to validate jTextfield within keypress

Tags: java, validation

im trying to validate a `jtextfield` from the `keypress` and would like it to throw an error message in a `jLabel`. I am trying to do this with in the code below.

```
private void jTextField2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   


    }
```

Comment: Add full reproducible code of what you have tried

Comment: Have you considered [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) ? What about [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) ?

Comment: No, How do i use it in this context?

Comment: [How to validate a JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749521/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so i'll answer instead. If you are looking to validate the input of the user as he/she type, you might wanna have a look at [javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

If you are simply looking to update a JLabel when the user types something, you should add a KeyboardListener to the JTextField. You have to be a bit careful with that tho, as swing doesn't guarantee the order in which listeners are called, meaning that the text may not have updated when the KeyboardListener is invoked.